# How to insert data for composite object?

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have table Person, student:

Person(id, ....): id is primary key and identity column.

Student(id, .....):  id is primary key and foreign key connect to person->ID

In ria service meta data, set Student as composite of Person:

```
[Include]
[Composition]
public Student Student { get; set; }
```

then I want to insert a new student data. what I did is something like:

```
Person p = new person(){....};

p.Student = new Student{....};

_context.People.AddObject(p);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

then I got error:

System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Student_Person". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.Person", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason of your error cause I'd like to see a little more code, but, I think you are missing the Association attribute in your Composition.